# Is it possible to see the resulting configuration Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Is there anyways to get all calculated config nginx after applying all conditions?
Something like phpinfo which returns local and master values.
Maybe command like nginx -t url

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to evaluate a config based on some url/input. Instead you can use debug mode.

First, you need a nginx version with debug enabled (compiled with `--with-debug` option). For some linux distributives it can found in a separate package like `nginx-debug`. The official docker image already includes `nginx-debug` binary.

Turn on `error_log` with `debug` level and do your requests.

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```

If you want to debug only specific requests, you can on debug mode per IP.

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
events {
    debug_connection 192.168.1.1;
    debug_connection 192.168.10.0/24;
}
```

Comment: The puropse to be ensure some config was applied. For examle i have folowing error:2023/12/07 14:48:20 [error] 1651171#1651171: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream ...
I find solutions ,but the promblem stll stayed. So i had the situation i dont sure the config is really apllied to endpoint,maybe regular wrong,maybe another else.With help of my mate i solved that.But the essense of that,i cant be sure some config setups was really applied and thats annoying

Comment: Debug will help you with it, there is all steps logged - locations, upstreams, connections.